# What's the proper way to get values for a dropdown from a table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Lets say I have a a table called... Person, I guess, and it has the columns Name, Email, AgeGroupId.

AgeGroupId is an int, which relates to the table AgeGroup.
Agegroup only has two columns: Id, and AgeGroupName.

Now, In my view, which is a page to edit a 'person', I want a dropdown box that has EVERY AgeGroupName as the text, and the Id as the value.
This way, later on, I can add a new 'age group' into my age group table, and all my drop down boxes will update. Or is there a better way I should be doing this?

I'm currently passing in my model, and doing this:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgeGroupId, @agegroups)

and at the top of the view, i'm making a SelectList with hardcoded values. I don't want them hard-coded in, I don't think? What would I do instead of @agegroup to get the list from the AgeGroups table?

Thanks.

Comment: See my tutorials   [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: @Kamyar , I haven't marked as answered yet because although I get it to populate the drop downs, I now get exceptions when updating the database(that i did not get before). I have been trying to debug myself for now so I can learn the most, but if I am unable to figure it out, i will post back.
I did however, upvote you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way seems to be from Kamyars edit, on the msdn blog here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/04/15/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is using ViewModels. Basically you'll have to create a viewmodel for your view and not pass the db result directly to your view. Something like:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person {get ; set;}
    public Dictionary<int, string> AgeGroups { get; set; }
    public PersonViewModel() {}
    public PersonViewModel(int personId)
    {
        var ctx = new Context();
        this.Person = ctx.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == personId);
        foreach(var ageGroup in ctx.AgeGroups)
        {
            this.AgeGroups.Add(ageGroup.Id, ageGroup.AgeGroupName);
        }
    }
```

Then your controller method will look like this:

```
public ActionResult Add(PersonViewModel vm)
{
    var ctx = new Context();
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ctx.Persons.Add(vm.Person);
        return View("Index"); 
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view, simply:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Person.AgeGroupId,
new SelectList(model.AgeGroups, "Id", "AgeGroupName"))
```

Of course, your view's model is now `PersonViewModel`.
**Update**
seems like ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools update adds drop down for relations by default. More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/04/15/asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx).